# mySQL slow counting primary keys with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, count

The following query is taking 5.5 seconds. Since this is a simple primary key count and both tables have <5000 records, I'm quite surprised at how slow it is. Is there any workaround to increase performance?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM users 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM clients 
       WHERE userID=users.id)=0
```

I'm counting the number of users who have no clients.

Comment: After adding an index on clients.userID, this query time comes down to 0.036s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u 
  left join clients c
  on u.id = c.userID 
  where u.id not in (select userID from clients)
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83b1/6)

Comment: Thanks a lot but this one is 5.99 seconds. It must be a problem with my database structure. I'll try adding an index on c.userID

Comment: After adding the index, this one comes down to 0.031s. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(*) 
FROM 
   users 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT 
      userID 
   FROM 
      clients 
   WHERE 
      userID=users.id)
```

Alternatively you can try this

```
SELECT 
   count(*) 
FROM 
   users u
LEFT JOIN  
   clients c
ON 
   u.id = c.userId
WHERE 
   c.userId IS null
```

Create index on `id` columns

Hope this helps

Comment: It's definitely faster - down to 3.69 seconds. Still very slow tho. Do I need to add an index to is if it's the primary key? I've always assumed the index on a primary key was implicit?

Comment: @cronoklee check the second query which I have posted and I assume that userId is not primary key in client table so create index there..

Comment: Thanks, second one is 3.76 seconds. I'll add the index and retest

Comment: Cool, with the index on clients.userID, your first query is 0.038 and the second is 0.059. Perfectly acceptable speeds! Thanks for the help Meherzad